# CartThrob: Modify Credit Cards Listed in Gateways Field

Tags: add-on, ee2, cartthrob

Is it possible to modify the credit cards listed in the `{gateway_fields}`. Or do you have to go through and do a full custom `{exp:cartthrob:checkout_form}` setup?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me I usually just copy/paste the sample HTML code given for that gateway (CT Settings > Payments) in my checkout template and modify as needed. They also recommend that in the [official docs](http://cartthrob.com/docs/tutorials/overriding_gateway_fields/index.html)